# How to change macOS region using the Terminal?

Tags: macos, monterey, internationalization

I am using macOS Monterey version 12.4.

I need to change the region using just the Terminal, how can I do it?

I tried to edit `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` and change `AppleLocale` variable. After rebooting, the region is not changed.

**EDIT:**

To explain it little bit, I currently have `Egypt` region and I need to change it to `Europe/Czechia` just using the Terminal.

I tried to run these commands and change the defaults -

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocal en_CZ
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale en_CZ
defaults write NSGlobalDomain OSLocale en_CZ
defaults write NSGlobalDomain region CZ
defaults write com.apple.dock region CZ
defaults write NSGlobalDomain loc en_GB:CZ
```

`defaults read | grep EG` after executing these commands -

```
  "cs-EG"
  "cs-EG"
  "L414-en-GB_EG" = "MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)";
  EGP = "18.83";
loc = "en_GB:EG";
CulturePreviousPreferredEditing = "en-EG";
OSLocale = "en_EG";
```

`defaults read | grep EG` after restarting the computer -

```
  "cs-EG"
AppleLocale = "en_EG";
    "cs-EG"
AppleLocale = "en_EG";
    "L414-en-GB_EG" = "MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)";
    EGP = "18.83";
loc = "en_GB:EG";
region = EG;
CulturePreviousPreferredEditing = "en-EG";
OSLocale = "en_EG";
```

[image: 1] (The region in `System Preferences`is not changed, after execution `defaults write` commands and even after restarting the OS).

Comment: Can you perform a defaults read on the value once you change it to what you want? (Or better diff the results from default location to the changed location?)

Comment: Of course, I have edited the question. I am not sure If I am changing the correct value in macOS `defaults`.